# Can't get proxy working in my react and node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making a react client app with a node.js express backend. Here is my project structure:

[image]

The client app is using a proxy, so in its package.json, it has the line:

```
"proxy": "https://localhost:5000"
```

This seems to cause the following error:

The browser requests a favicon.ico at the URL `/favicon.ico`. Normally, this would be a request to the react app, so the request would be made to `localhost:3000/favicon.ico`. But since we're now using a proxy, the request gets sent to `localhost:5000/favicon.ico`, note the change in port number. This causes a proxy error, here's what it says in the terminal:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /favicon.ico from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:5000.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (EPROTO).
```

In the browser, it says `GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

I'm afraid that this problem will cause other problems with my app, so I want to get it out of the way. I've tried to do this in my server.js file:

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  console.log("got to server")
  res.send("favicon placeholder")
})
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't change the behaviour of the app. The exact same error happens, and the console.log doesn't output anything, which makes me think that nothing even gets routed to the server. Now, here's the most important question: **Why is this?** Why doesn't the request go to the server?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
Here's the package.json file of the server, in the home folder.
home/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sentify-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the client app is using a proxy? Are you setting proxy settings on your ajax client?  If you attempt to make ajax calls to a different origin (protocol://host:port) than your page is served on you will run into CORS issues.  The standard approach to a web application that serves content on different ports is a reverse proxy through nginix/apache/IIS.

Comment: What proxy do you use? It looks like the proxy is for the react app only, not used by the browser itself. The browser requests the favicon completely independent of your react app and is so not using the proxy. I assume the 500 comes from the setup that disallows now the browser accessing the port 3000?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the lingo, but here's what I'm doing: I'm hosting a server at port 5000 and the client app at 3000. Then in the package.json file of the client app I have specified the proxy field as `"localhost:5000"`. This is to avoid CORS issues when making API calls to twitter, in my case. I make the API calls in my server.js file and serve them to the client app.

Comment: @CFrei, then why is it saying `Could not proxy request /favicon.ico from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:5000.` ? It looks like it's indeed doing something with a proxy. And what do you mean by what proxy I use? I have given all the information, all I've done is specify a proxy field in the package.json of the client app.

Comment: You need to start your back-end server and client concurrently that means you need to watch your express server while at the same time npm start your react app for it to proxy a request. In addition, for react, are you using ajax to try and fetch that from your server?

Comment: I think I have. See my edit. As to your second question, it shouldn't matter, because this is not an API call from the client that's failing, it's the browser making an APi call by itself, right?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling I found the problem. The `proxy` field in the package.json file is a `https` url. Changing it to `http` sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and realized that I was inside the client folder rather than the parent server folder when I ran "npm start", just double check your folder.

Answer (score 0):

it's work if you use http instead of https